# Rebind existing HTML Table with Json result in AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a HTML table on a page. There is a button on this page that opens a modal popup which contains controls that can remove a row from the database table that populates the fore-mentioned HTML Table.

If an entry is removed from the database I would therefore need the table to be re-loaded/re-bound to show the latest results in the database table it is representing.

When removing an entry in the modal popup, a call is made to a C# Controller/Action using Ajax and so the obvious thing to do is to get the table in JQuery, clear it down then iterate through the Json result, adding each row in afresh. However, in this particular example there is a lot of code involved in that - so I am looking for a short cut essentially.

I am hoping that Javascript or Jquery has some kind of magical function that recognizes that the table has already been defined and is clever enough to map the Json to the correct positions in the table?!?!

I think I know there is not such a thing but would like to get some confirmation from others who may be more 'in the know'?

Comment: No, there's no magic JavaScript or jQuery function for this. There are plugins like Datatables and jQgrid that automate it.

Comment: This is where ReactJS and AngularJS shine. These types of scenarios are handled easily with the [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback both... I have been meaning to get more into React and Angular so have even more of a reason to now. Will investigate possibilities with Datatables and jqGrid in the meantime I think. Thanks both!